# Can I change default WIN-KEY (up/down/left/right) window dock behavior/sizes?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-key

In Windows 7 I can hold the WINDOWS key and press a directional key (left, right, up, down) and the current active window will dock to left half of the screen, right half of the screen, maximized and restored (respectively).

Is it possible to either add additional behaviors (such as left two thirds, right third, etc)?  Or perhaps is it possible to change the width of these locations so I can set the "left half" to actually be about 33% of the screen?

Comment: Have a look at the answers here: http://superuser.com/questions/83470/in-windows-7-is-there-a-way-to-snap-a-window-to-a-quarter-of-the-screen-instead

Answer (score 2):

1. [First disable the built in windows shortcuts](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm).
2. Install [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and go nuts. It should be able to do all that you are asking and much much more.

EDIT: Take a look at link below which is an AutoHotKey script which replicates the Windows 7 actions. You can modify it to your own tastes.

www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/51720-windows-7-like-window-positioning-for-xp-and-vista/

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some AutoHotKey scripts, and one of them is to move windows by keyboard. You can check them out at [**rwintools**](http://code.google.com/p/rwintools/).

If you don't want all the other tools in my collection, you can just get the script for moving windows ([**move-window.ahk**](http://code.google.com/p/rwintools/source/browse/ahk-scripts/move-window.ahk)) and its dependency ([**common.ahi**](http://code.google.com/p/rwintools/source/browse/ahk-scripts/common.ahi)).

The following are keyboard hot keys to move the current active window:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>: move the current window, using all the visible windows as "stop sign"
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>: dock
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>: move the left-upper corner of the current window, using all the visible windows as "stop sign"
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>: move the right-bottom corner of the current window, using all the visible windows as "stop sign"
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>: move the current window to the left-upper corner of the primary display.

You need to disable the built-in hot keys.

Comment: You need to disable the built-in hot keys.

How to disable it in windows 10 ? I have got no idea after trying those tutorial on the net

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of is with [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/). It allows you to create hotkeys and titlebar buttons for just about anything. It's a great free window manager. I use it on all of my computers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the default configuration.

But you can try WindowPadX.

http://hoppfrosch.github.io/WindowPadX/files/WindowPadX-ahk.html

The default config uses the Windows Keys + Numkeys to move the windows. Just a little reminder: the default config uses the numpad 0 as a modifier - without the use of the Windows Key. So, if you try to type "01", it will interfere with your current screen.