# Is there a way to "side-snap" more than 50% in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, aero-snap

I can't find anything about this on the web, and I assume it MIGHT be possible **without using third-party software**.

**I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to "*side-snap*" a window with a default setting of more than 50%.**

By side-snapping I mean dragging a window to the side and allowing windows to re-size and re-position it. Also can be done by using *windows + left* or *windows + right*.

I'm thinking there should be a settings file somewhere, of a key in the registry, but I'm hoping someone has already gone through the steps.

I can see there's an unanswered question related to this so I'm a bit perplex... (https://superuser.com/questions/810069/change-the-width-of-windows-side-by-side-arrangement-to-be-larger-than-that)

Comment: I don't believe it's possible without a 3rd party program.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/83470/in-windows-7-is-there-a-way-to-snap-a-window-to-a-quarter-of-the-screen-instead

Here's on answered on here, but it was 4 years ago so might be completely worthless now.

Comment: This will be possible in Windows 10